# Android ViewPager Bug on Swipe

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have this weird issue with the viewPager. When I swipe from one fragment to the next and then swipe back, the layout is correct, but when pressing an element (Listview item for example), the previous java code still did not update with the view. I don't know if I can explain this any better, as it works when I play with the swipe until the fragment works like its supposed to. here is my code:

Main.Java:

```
public class Main extends FragmentActivity {

SectionsPagerAdapter mAdapter;

ViewPager mViewPager;

// for alert transitions
AlertDialog dialog;

// share button
private ShareActionProvider mShareActionProvider;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // set up button
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the app.
    mAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(
            getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    mViewPager.setPageTransformer(true, new DepthPageTransformer());



}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (mViewPager.getCurrentItem() == 0) {
        // If the user is currently looking at the first step, allow the system to handle the
        // Back button. This calls finish() on this activity and pops the back stack.
        super.onBackPressed();
    } else {
        // Otherwise, select the previous step.
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(mViewPager.getCurrentItem() - 1);
    }
}
}
```

SectionsPagerAdapter.java:

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    switch (position){

    case 0:
        return new Important();
    case 1:
        return new Propositions();
    case 2:
        return new Information();
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // Show 3 total pages.
    return 3;
}



@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        return ("Important Dates").toUpperCase(l);
    case 1:
        return ("Props").toUpperCase(l);
    case 2:
        return ("Information").toUpperCase(l);
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

The Fragments all use the onCreateView() method.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Not sure if I got the problem, but you should know that the `ViewPager` prepares/creates always two fragments for quicker access. So if you swipe to the second fragment and back afterwards, the first fragment won't be recreated.

Comment: Yea that is understandable, my problem is if I have one fragment is a listView, and the second is a gridView, when I swipe to the gridView it works fine. However, when I swipe back to the listView, it shows the layout, but when I press the screen it acts like the gridView is still showing and will behave as if I was still on the second fragment.

Comment: Ah ok, I had this issue as well some time ago :) looked really wired. All I remember is that there was something wrong with the fragment manager transactions. For some reasons I struggled with using constructors directly (`new Important()`) so I used a `newInstance()` method (see https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/ViewPager-with-FragmentPagerAdapter). If that doesn't help, may be you compare your code with that nice sample.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a late response, but I've experienced the same issue. 
The problem was the `DepthPageTransformer` you are using from the Android Developers example for `PageTransformer`.

There is a bug with stacking fragments and layer priority, I assume. By fixing the custom `PageTransformer` will fix your "swipe back" issue. Or if you don't mind the animation, just remove your custom `PageTransformer` and use the default animation (by adding nothing).